# How to show distributions of multiple features in one tensor in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, visualization, tensorboard

I have a tensor `X` which is an output of the batch normalization layer (`tf.layers.batch_normalization`) and has the shape of `[batch_size, 15]`. To monitor its distribution, I created a histogram for `X` with `tf.summary.histogram('out_BN_0', X)`. The graph is what I got in Tensorboard after > 70k steps (~ 130 epoches). Is it the average results of all 15 features? or any particular feature in `X`? How do I get the distribution of just one feature (e.g. 5th)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about building a histogram per each feature?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 100
num_features = 15

X = tf.constant(np.random.uniform(size=(batch_size, num_features)))
hists = {feature_index: tf.summary.histogram(f'hist_{feature_index}', X[:, feature_index]) 
              for feature_index in range(num_features)}
```

Comment: Thanks, MZHm. Is the letter 'f' in tf.summary.histogram necessary?